# I want to create expandable list view on button click

Tags: android

I want to load expandable list view on button click .
On first activity i have 2 buttons. when i click on button 1 it will load expandable list view with 10 items and when i click on button 2 it will load expandable list view with 5 items.
Can anybody help me how to do this.

> MainAcitivy

```
private void prepareList(String sub) {
    listHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> a1 = null;
    List<String> a2 = null;
    List<String> a3 = null;
    List<String> a4 = null;
    List<String> a5 = null;
    List<String> a6 = null;
    List<String> a7 = null;
    List<String> a8 = null;
    List<String> a9 = null;
    List<String> a10 = null;

    if (sub.equalsIgnoreCase("btn1")) {
        // Adding Child Data
        listHeader.add("1. Hello1");
        listHeader.add("2. Hello2");
        listHeader.add("3. Hello3");
        listHeader.add("4. Hello4");
        listHeader.add("5. Hello5");
        listHeader.add("6. Hello6");
        listHeader.add("7. Hello7");
        listHeader.add("8. Hello8");
        listHeader.add("9. Hello9");
        listHeader.add("10. Hello10");

        // Adding Child Data
        a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a1.add("1");

        a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a2.add("2");

        a3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a3.add("3");

        a4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a4.add("4");

        a5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a5.add("5");

        a6 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a6.add("6");

        a7 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a7.add("7");

        a8 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a8.add("8");

        a9 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a9.add("9");

        a10 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a10.add("10");
    }
    else if (sub.equalsIgnoreCase("btn2")) {
        listHeader.add("1. Hello1");
        listHeader.add("2. Hello2");
        listHeader.add("3. Hello3");
        listHeader.add("4. Hello4");
        listHeader.add("5. Hello5");

        // Adding Child Data
        a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a1.add("1");

        a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a2.add("2");

        a3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a3.add("3");

        a4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a4.add("4");

        a5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a5.add("5");
    }
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(0), a1);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(1), a2);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(2), a3);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(3), a4);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(4), a5);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(5), a6);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(6), a7);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(7), a8);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(8), a9);
    listChild.put(listHeader.get(9), a10);
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you want to load the list with x number of Groups or do you want to load a specific expandable list view Group with x number of Childs ?

Comment: @raxelsson : specific number of group

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha : look at the code i'm passing text on button click through intent and checking in if condition

Comment: Is the numbers of items fixed??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: yes on button 1 click it will load with 10 item and on button 2 click it will load with 5 item but when i click on button 2 it was showing me error IndexOutOfBoundException

Answer (score 0):

You could try with adding onClick in your adapter like this

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int pos, boolean arg1, View convertView, ViewGroup arg3) {

   if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawerlayout, null);
   }
   convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });
}
```

OR take a look at this whole example http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have the buttons in your `MainActivity.java` class.

Here's some code that I would try, I have not tested this in action but it might point you in the right direction.

Make your MainActivity handle your clicks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

this makes you have to override a method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

you should have IDs on your buttons if you've put them in a xml layout. And then you can handle the click in this overridden metho

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btn1:
           List<String> items1 = new ArrayList<String>("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",)
           loadGroups(items1);
           break;
      case R.id.btn2:
           List<String> items2 = new ArrayList<String>("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",)               
           loadGroups(items2);
           break;
   }
}
```

then implement this `loadGroups()` method something like this.

```
private void loadGroups(List<String> groups) {
   yourExpandableListView.setAdapter(new MyExpListAdapter(groups));            
}
```

this will update your expandable list view with new data and call notifyDataSetChanged() which will redraw your items in the adapter.

In a expandable list view you should also have a  `Map<String, List<String>>` which is supposed to contain the groups with its childs.

More details is found at [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Sorry that I haven't answered with a complete solution. I hope this helps a little.